# Are Deleuze's "schizos" = his "people to come"?

Tags: deleuze, deleuze-and-guattari, futurology

Are Deleuze's "schizos" = his "people to come"? I've read a very little Deleuze. The former is from 'anti-oedipus', the latter from a discussion of Klee in 'Qu’est-ce que la philosophie'? Are they the same people? I think the latter write *meaninglessly*, which is why I ask.